# Inserting a formula into a cell with the appropriate row (Google Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to use google scripts to insert a formula into each cell in a column, but to change the formula to use the appropriate row.

On the front-end of google sheets, I'd just select the whole column and paste. The sheets would automatically update the cells to match the new row (unless I put a $).  I can't figure out the equivalent in scripts.

Thanks again!

Comment: Although I'm worried whether you can understand my English, I thought that in your question, when you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image and also provide your current script and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For instance

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  for (var row = 2; row <= sh.getLastRow(); row++) {
    sh.getRange('B' + row).setFormula('=A' + row)
  }
```